# Maven doesn't pick up resources on jenkins(linux)

Tags: java, angular, maven, spring-boot

I'm having really weird issue - I have created multi-module java project that creates "fat-jar". Unfortunetly the "frontend" module jar doesn't have resources in it when launched on jenkins(linux) - it does work on Windows for some reason:

This is the "frontend" pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.frontend</groupId>
  <artifactId>frontend-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>dist</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>node build app</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I have tried with:

```
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
```

But that did not help neither.

The default npm build goal is

```
ng build --output-path dist/META-INF/resources
```

Jar file in target does not include files from "dist" -> it also does not work when I create it in default location `src/main/resources`

The maven log output includes this:

```
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
```

The dist directory is created and filled during build. Maven locates files on Windows but does not on Jenkins.

EDIT:

The maven goals are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could check few things on Jenkins. First if mvn goal is exactly same. Second, whether all resources are checked out properly or not. Also, see if file write permission are there for the linux user used by Jenkins process. Finally, append a -X behind your goals on Jenkins to see maven logs in detail and debug your issue.

Comment: the goals are the same. Like i said - the dist directory (which contains resources) is created and filled by angular generated files - did you mean someting else by "checked out properly"?. I have appended -X - the only thing that I have found interesting is the warning that I have in original question -> should I look for something else?

Comment: See if file write permission are there for the linux user used by Jenkins process